# Is it possible to run arbitrary Python or R scripts on a "Spark with Yarn" cluster?

Tags: r, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to make a cluster that does some big data activities. I'm not sure whether 'SPARK with YARN' cluster can run Python or R script.

If it is possible, what is the simplest way to run those scripts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [Hadoop Streaming](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) which allows you to run Hadoop jobs created using an arbitrary programming language. You simply need to provide a pair of executables (e.g. Python scripts) - one for the map phase (going from input data to a set of intermediate key-value pairs), and one for the reduce phase (going from those intermediate key-value pairs to the output of your job).

Comment: thanks for the help! I have some questions about Hadoop Streaming.    1. So, executing a python script with HS doesn't require SPARK?    2. Input/output is just directory location where mapper and reducer are, and mapper/reducer is where actual python script goes. Is this right?